# Inconsistencies in Dart ListBase

Tags: list, function, dart

Is there any particular reason for the inconsistent return types of the functions in Dart's ListBase class?

Some of the functions do what (as a functional programmer) I would expect, that is: List -> (apply function) -> List. These include: `take`, `skip`, `reversed`.

Others do not: thus `l.removeLast()` returns just the final element of the list; to get the List without the final element, you have to use a cascade: `l..removeLast()`.

Others return a lazy Iterable, which requires further work to retrieve the list: `newl = l.map(f).toList()`.

Some functions operate more like properties `l.last`, as opposed to functions `l.removeLast()`

Is there some subtle reason for these choices?

Comment: `take`, `skip` and `reversed` do not return a List. They return an Iterable.

Comment: Yes. I meant to say that as they are not _lazy_ Iterables, they act differently from `map`, `where`, `skipWhile`, `takeWhile`, which need a subsequent `.toList()` to retrieve the contents.

Comment: they are exactly the same. They return Iterables backed by the original list. You don't need "toList()" for the others either, if you only use Iterable functions: l.map(f).first. l.where(f).isNotEmpty, ...

Comment: I don't see that consistency across ListBase that you seem to. To reverse an Iterable, the syntax is `l.reversed`; To shuffle an Iterable, the syntax is `l..shuffle();` Hence my original question; is there some subtle reason for this?

Comment: My comment was not about `shuffle`, but `take`, `skip` and `reversed`. These are exactly the same as `map`, `where`, ... There are two kinds of functions: the ones that return an `Iterable` (lazy and backed by the original list), and in-place. `sort`, `shuffle`, `add`, `removeLast`, are in the latter category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mbmcavoy is right. Dart is an imperative language and many `List` members modify the list in-place. The most prominent is the operator `[]=`, but `sort`, `shuffle`, `add`, `removeLast`, etc. fall into the same category.

In addition to these imperative members, List inherits some functional-style members from `Iterable`: `skip`, `take`, `where`, `map`, etc. These are lazy and do not modify the List in place. They are backed by the original list. Modifying the backing list, will change the result of iterating over the iterable. `List` furthermore adds a few lazy members, like `reversed`.

To avoid confusion, lazy members always return an `Iterable` and not an object implementing the `List` interface. Some of the iterables guarantee fast `length` and index-operators (like `take`, `skip` and `reversed`) and could easily implement the `List` interface. However, this would inevitably lead to bugs, since they are lazy and backed by the original list.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I have not yet used Dart specifically, but hope to soon.)

Dart is not a functional programming language, which may the the source of your confusion.

Methods, such as `.removeLast()` are intended to change the state of the object they are called upon. The operation performed by `l.removeLast()` is to modify l so that it no longer contains the last item. You can access the resulting list by simply using `l` in your next statement.

(Note they are called "methods" rather than "functions", as they are not truly functions in the mathematical sense.)

The choice to return the removed item rather than the remaining list is a convenience. most frequently, the program will need to do something with the removed item (like move it to a different list).

For other methods, the returned data will relate to a common usage scenario, but it isn't always necessary to capture it.